# Get the quantity a user bought

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a web application. Users need to buy packs of credits to use this web application. For instance, one pack of 5000 credits costs 4.99 USD. I use Stripe to manage the purchasing. I can use the following code to create a checkout session where users can adjust the quantity to buy.

```
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      customer: customer.id,
      mode: "payment",
      line_items: [
        {
          price: priceId,
          quantity: 1,
          adjustable_quantity: {
            enabled: true,
            minimum: 1,
            maximum: 10,
          },
        },
      ],
      success_url: successUrl,
      expand: ['line_items'],
    });

    console.log("session.line_items.data", session.line_items.data)
```

After the purchasing, I would like to know what's the quantity the user decided to buy. I cannot find it in `session.line_items.data`. Does anyone know where I can get this information?

PS: here is the printed `session.line_items.data`, where `quantity` is `1`, while I entered more than 1 in my checkout session.

```
session.line_items.data [
  {
    id: 'li_1NkQLWKr7t8UXDrfh27ztJyS',
    object: 'item',
    amount_discount: 0,
    amount_subtotal: 499,
    amount_tax: 0,
    amount_total: 499,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Pack of 5000 credits',
    price: {
      id: 'price_1NkPz7Kr7t8UXDrfWPexeF0Y',
      object: 'price',
      active: true,
      billing_scheme: 'per_unit',
      created: 1693308085,
      currency: 'usd',
      custom_unit_amount: null,
      livemode: false,
      lookup_key: null,
      metadata: {},
      nickname: null,
      product: 'prod_OXUzBNts9jZ47m',
      recurring: null,
      tax_behavior: 'unspecified',
      tiers_mode: null,
      transform_quantity: null,
      type: 'one_time',
      unit_amount: 499,
      unit_amount_decimal: '499'
    },
    quantity: 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking at it when the Session is *completed* ? You wouldn't see it until then.

I can see it in `line_items.data[].quantity`.

Note that it's not populated on the `checkout.session.completed` event, or in a normal `retrieve()` function, you have to explicitly `expand` your `line_items` array in your retrieve / list call (but again, only once the Session is completed).

Comment: How could I get the quantity when the Session is completed? I appended in the OP the result of `console.log("session.line_items.data", session.line_items.data)` just after `await stripe.checkout.sessions.create`, the quantity was wrong.

Comment: This is what you say in your post: "After the purchasing, I would like to know what's the quantity the user decided to buy". *After the purchasing* means *after the customer completes the session*. Obviously, this doesn't happen just from *creating* the session. You create the Session, redirect your customer to it, the customer completes it, you get a `checkout.sesison.completed` event, retrieve it and find the selected quantity.

Comment: So I need to use Stripe Webhook to catch the `checkout.sesison.completed` event?

Comment: Preferrably, yes. Technically, you can just keep retrieving the Session until it's completed, which would do the same, but for your production build, webhooks would really be best here.