# Why can I get customer email from checkout session of stripe in node.js

Tags: node.js, email, stripe-payments, payment

I want to get customer email after payment of stripe.
I can see information related to the payment using my account in stripe.
But I can't get customer emails using API in the backend.

This is my backend code.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_********');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');



const app = express();
const YOUR_DOMAIN = 'http://localhost:3000/buy';


app.use(cors())
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {

    const priceID = 'price_******';
    const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
        {
            price: priceID,
            quantity: 1,
        },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${YOUR_DOMAIN}?canceled=true`,
    });
    
    const sessionId = session.id;
    if(sessionId){

        //--------     First try     --------//
        const customers = await stripe.customers.list({});
        customers.data.forEach(customer => {
            console.log(customer.email);
        });
        const email = session.customer_email;

        //--------     Second try     --------//
        stripe.charges.list({ limit: 10 }, (err, charges) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error retrieving charges:', err);
                return;
            }
          
            charges.data.forEach(charge => {
                const customerEmail = charge.receipt_email;
                console.log('Customer Email:', customerEmail);
            });
        });

        res.send({id:session.id});
    }
    
});

app.listen(4242, () => console.log('Running on port 4242'));
```

But I can only see null values instead of customer emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have any customer information here because you just created the Checkout Session, and no one has paid for it.

A CheckoutSession needed to be created and paid during 2 separated steps. (See [Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment)) Only after it is paid, you can receive the webhook event checkout.session.completed and [able to extract the customer information](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) from there.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly answer. But I don' understand what you mean. So how do I have to change my code? If you know sample github link, could you share me that?

Answer (score 0):

To add to @orakaro’s answer, you’re calling a customers.list() at some point. You’ll never get any Customer object from Sessions in payment mode, just guest customers (unless you’re running on older API versions).

If you want your Sessions to create Customer objects when they complete, use customer_creation:’always’ in your sessions.create().

That said, a Customer object won’t be necessary to get the email

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand perfectly. So, how do I have to change my code? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Your misunderstanding is basically the same as what I explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76999952/get-the-quantity-a-user-bought with checkout, you don’t get any info until the customer completes the session. In your case, you need to listen for the completed event or retrieve the session once it’s completed to get the customer email. My point was that even then, you won’t have a Customer object, since this is payment mode. If you want to create actual Customers, I’ve provided the exact argument to set.