# Stripe session object has null customer field in subscription mode

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

I am in a stripe test environment. When a subscription is made stripe is not returning the customer id although I can see it in the dashboard.

Here is my endpoint code(node.js):

```
const { priceId } = req.body;

const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  mode: "subscription",
  line_items: [
    {
      price: priceId,
      // For metered billing, do not pass quantity
      quantity: 1,
    },
  ],
  // {CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID} is a string literal; do not change it!
  // the actual Session ID is returned in the query parameter when your customer
  // is redirected to the success page.
  success_url:
    "http://localhost:5000/payment-success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
  cancel_url: "http://localhost:5000/payment-failed",
});

console.log(session.customer) //null
```

I successfully receive the entire object but can't access customer field

I will appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure your issue is the same misunderstanding as this:
[Get the quantity a user bought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76999952/get-the-quantity-a-user-bought/77000130?noredirect=1#comment135749177_77000130)

Customer data is created when the customer submits the Session, not when you create it.
What you create is just a blank form instance.

Try retrieving the Session after it’s completed (checkout.session.completed event).

Comment: Yeah customer is never created when creating session instance. I solved this by creating a customer manually (saving in db) and passing that customer to session. In this way webhooks return that same customer id.